# Fullcalendar - drop external element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm able to drop external element to calendar, however I'm unable to determine the start / end of newly dropped event.

According to docs, `drop` has a callback function called when a valid jQuery UI draggable has been dropped onto the calendar.

```
function( date, allDay, jsEvent, ui ) { }
```

`date` holds the JavaScript Date object of where the draggable was dropped.

Now I'm able to get `start` value, however the object, however I couldn't find `end`  value.

Thanks

Comment: If the dropped item has a data-duration (see [droppable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/) documentation) you can add it to the start to get the end; if the dropped item has event data, [eventReceive](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/) will be available and passed the event after the drop and after event has been rendered.

Comment: @smcd your comment should be an answer, thank you :)